# MYSQL to Google chart(Line chart)

Tags: php, mysql, charts

I am trying to display mysql data by using google chart in the form of a line chart.I think the problem is the part when Im trying to format the data for google charts.What is wrong with my codes?

```
$sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM real_price");

$data = array (
    'cols' => array(  
        array('id' => 'period', 'label' => 'Period', 'type' => 'string'), 
        array('id' => 'demand', 'label' => 'Demand(MW)', 'type' => 'number')

    ),
    'rows' => array();
);

while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)){
 $data['rows'][] = array('c' => array(
        array('v' => $res['Period']),
        array('v' => $res['Demand(MW)'])
    ));
}
$json = json_encode($data);
?>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.DataTable(<?php echo $json ?>);

        var options = {
          title: 'Price information'
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide more information about what is the actual problem you are facing

Comment: The code is supposed to display a line chart, however it gave me a  blank page when I run the script.I suspect that the json format is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think the json format is wrong, it should be as

```
     $sth = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM real_price");
     $data = array(array("Period", "Demand(MW)"));

     while ($res = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)){
             $data[] = array($res['Period'], $res['Demand(MW)']);
     }

     $json = json_encode($data);
```